# Use python to query mysql:what encoding and decoding should be used when query condition has Chinese characters

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, decode

First , below is my mysql server encoding configurations:

server1:

```
1   character_set_client    utf8
2   character_set_connection    utf8
3   character_set_database  utf8
4   character_set_filesystem    binary
5   character_set_results   utf8
6   character_set_server    utf8
7   character_set_system    utf8
```

I am trying to use python to connect to this mysql db and query some data using Chinese query conditions.

Some data sample in this db is like this:

[image]

My sampale python code is just like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

# 打开数据库连接
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="1.1.1.1.",user="online",passwd="hdhjjdd",port=3406,db="data_platform")

cursor = conn.cursor()
name = "赵胜".decode("utf-8")
sql="select user_name, call_params from tb_user_log where   user_name='%s' order by user_name desc"  %(name.encode("utf-8"))

count = cursor.execute(sql)

print count #always 0 ,cannot query out any data

#执行SQL,创建一个数据库.
```

This query cannot query out any data.I think it is the encoding problem .Since it is a online database, I cannot change the encoding configuration of mysql server. So , I don't know how to modify my python code to make the chinese query condition works.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `"赵胜".decode("utf-8")` is wrong, returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` while `"赵胜".encode("utf-8")` returns byte sequence `b'\xe8\xb5\xb5\xe8\x83\x9c'`

Comment: That is the correct hex.  But I don't think you need `encode()` or `decode()`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.